# Android: widget align question

Tags: android, widget

in a RelativeLayout I have an Imageview that serves as the background of the widget and a RelativeLayout. The RelativeLayout is "on" the Imageview, but i want it to be in the center of the Imageview. How can i align it to it?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="470px"
    android:layout_height="120px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlayout"
    >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView00"
     android:layout_width="470px"
     android:layout_height="120px"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      >
</ImageView>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="470px"
    android:layout_height="120px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlayoutbelso"
    >
...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: As a side note, have you considered using android:background on the top-most RelativeLayout rather than using an ImageView ?

Comment: That was the first thing to do but it was not working the way i wanted thas why i decided to use a separate imageview. I don't remember the reason for it, it was weeks ago when i created the widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `android:layout_centerInParent` to true on your inner relative layout (you can probably remove the gravity flags too at this point).

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageView and RelativeLayouts have exactly the same layout sizes (width and height), so the RelativeLayout can't really be centered in the ImageView. You could try setting the RelativeLayout layout sizes to wrap_content, and set android:layout_centerInParent="true" (as David said).